# EMR serverless NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/progress/TransferListener

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-emr

I have a spark application which reads parquet files from S3. My pipeline is pretty simple and it works fine on my local cluster.
Here is the relevant part where I read the parquet:

```
final Dataset<Row> dataset = session
        .read()
        .option("mergeSchema", "true")
        .option("recursiveFileLookup", true)
        .parquet(s3Path);
```

However, when I try to run the same jar on serverless EMR, I get the above error.
My serverless emr version is `emr-6.15.0`.
Spark version is `3.4.1`

I have passed these jars to my conf

`--conf spark.jars=s3://<bucker>/<prefix>/hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar,s3://<bucker>/<prefix>/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.569.jar,s3://<bucker>/<prefix>/aws-java-sdk-1.12.569.jar,s3://<bucker>/<prefix>/aws-crt-0.28.10.jar`

Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/progress/TransferListener
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:548)
    at com.apple.weather.MyJobMainClass.loadParquet(MyJobMainClass.java:53)
    at com.apple.weather.MyJobMainClass.main(MyJobMainClass.java:91)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1066)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1158)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.TransferListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
```

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError not necessarily means there is issue with classPath, it could also suggest some initialization issue. such as there is some static block which is causing the issue.

Comment: Try looking for other stack traces.

Comment: unfortunately that is the only thing that stands out. Rest of the logs match with my local logs where the job starts up successfully.

Answer (score 0):

One similar problem i faced was with Hadoop versions mismatch, in my local it was working fine, but I was getting the issue while running on EMR.

After careful analysis what I found out was, in our company, we were using private repository.
So in my local I was able to download ****hadoop, hadoop-aws**** and all the other related dependencies of same version. But on EMR, since it was not able to access few of private repositories, it was pulling latest dependency from maven central. This caused mismatch between few of Hadoop related dependencies.

What you can do is, in build stage, you can print dependency tree, and verify all the related dependencies are on same version or not.

Command to check the same is.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked the dependencies and made sure the exact versions were used. Based on this: https://web.archive.org/web/20170718025436/https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-file-system-s3/

I swithced from using `s3a` to `s3` and with that one change, my error seems to be gone.